# Beeping in My home

Tags: electrical

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is beeping in my house?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10871/what-is-beeping-in-my-house)

For the past 3 weeks there has been a beeping in my house.  It sounds like a smoke alarm.  It beeps at about 40 second intervals.  Early on it would stop beeping for a few hours.  Now it is every 40 seconds.

I have long ago taken down the smoke detectors, removed the batteries and put them in the other side of the house also.

I  turned off all power, but it continues to beep. So it seems to me it must be battery powered -- right?

I have had service visits from the AC and Security services.

I have a well and septic system.  The septic system is a loud blaring noise, not a beep. Help!

An appliance expert says it is not the stove.  I have taken the microwave outside the house.

It is not a beep like you might get from a computer or a watch.  It is loud like a smoke detector.

Comment: Yep - had the same issue in a house we rented. During renovation somebody put plaster board over an old smoke detector. about 1 year in it beeped.. and beeped... we searched everywhere. Eventually after 2 months it stopped. It was annoying. You can try and follow the sound and there were it sounds loudest.. starting going into the walls.. if you want.. or jsut wait another month.. or two

Comment: Or someone was extra safety conscious and has installed one in the attic as attic fires are able to spread quickly and just about burn a house down before you ever get alerted down in the living area. Do you have a pulldown attic access door somewhere in the house?

Comment: or basement near the furnace?

Comment: I assume you ruled out the refrigerator and freezer. If doors are not tight closed, they may beep.

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts.  The house is 12 years old so I don't think that there is one in the walls -- though that is where it sounds it is..  I have been in the attic.  In the attic you can barely hear the sound and a could not find a detector.  Refrigerator and freezer doors are closed

Comment: Could it be a ***radon*** detector?