# Strange beeping in house

Tags: troubleshooting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [what is beeping in my house?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10871/what-is-beeping-in-my-house)

I've tried ALL the suggestions on this site and the beeping continues, every 20 minutes, day and night. Been going on for two months. Have replaced literally everything with a battery on the first floor, which is where we hear it. Also, it moves around, sometimes sounding like it's coming from the gas fireplace and sometimes from the front hallway. Electricians had no idea. Help!

Comment: Are your smoke alarms hard wired?

Comment: Maybe an [Annoy-a-tron](http://www.thinkgeek.com/product/8c52/)?