# What could be causing this strange intermittent sound?

Tags: noise, troubleshooting

I've seen that there are already some questions about odd sounds but I thought if anywhere is likely to provide a specific answer or a suggestion, here would be a good place to look.

I have a beeping sound that goes off from what appears to be the fridge, I only assume that because it can only really be heard in the kitchen, and its coming from that corner. It happens around about 1-2 times a minute, it isn't particularly loud but I can notice it.

I've managed to make a [short video of the sound](http://youtu.be/XZnr-9JPMeA) which I took on my phone, then cut, cleaned and boosted the audio so you should be able to hear it.

I've already made a note of other suggestions on [this page](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10871/what-is-beeping-in-my-house) but if anyone know exactly what it is already that would be cool.

Comment: I don't think "cut, cleaned, and boosted the audio" helped. It now sounds like a chipmunk is stuck in your attic or aliens, take your pick. Since it sounds like you can't isolate where this is coming from my ear but have use and knowledge of audio editing software, why not take sampling from around the room and analyze on the computer which one is the loudest and isolate where it is from that information.

Comment: This video was taken with my phone (not amazing but what I have to hand) in the original master file of the video you could only just hear it, I know it sounds weird but trust me, that is what it sounds like. I could try to samples but I think that even with decent recording equipment, it would just get lost and unable to pick it out from the ambient sound

Comment: OK - First of all that is one of the most useless videos I have seen but also funniest.  Can we just hear the regular video clip?

Comment: I struggle to see why its one of the funniest... but no thats kind of the point, you cant HEAR the regular video clip, the sound peaks at about -48db on the original recording, meaning that you can only just hear it with the volume fully up wearing very good headphones. I only included the video file so you could hear the exact noise, rather than, 'I'm hearing a beep'

Comment: The practical joker in me thinks of this device  http://www.thinkgeek.com/product/b278/?srp=6 for random beeping sounds.

Answer (score 1):

My best guess (not knowing the model of refrigerator) is a faulty door timer or over-temperature sensor. A beep sounds on various models to remind you that you've left the door open too long.

Answer (score 1):

My first instinct is that it might be an ice maker in the fridge (have you tried making sure that you can get clean, fresh ice if you have one?). From what I can hear, it does not sound like a specific "beep" one might hear from an electronic device. Those generally have a clear, monotone which is often hard to mistake. Instead this sounds like something electrical/mechanical which is failing somehow. If that is the case, then the ice maker is a prime suspect.