# How can I determine which equipment in my basement is beeping periodically?

Tags: noise

I have a few pieces of equipment in the basement and one of them is beeping every 2 hours (approximately) or so.

1) Sump Pump

2) Radon Mitigation System.

3) Verizon Fios - Optical Network Terminal (ONT).

4) Furnace

5) Water heater

How do I identify which one is making the beeping sound?

Comment: often equipment will have a light indicating an error or low battery. My guess would be to check the sump pump, radon, and ONT as I don't believe the furnace or water heater will beep

Comment: sump pump doesn't have a battery backup.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [what is beeping in my house?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/10871/what-is-beeping-in-my-house)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's almost certainly your FiOS ONT. The power supply contains a battery, and it beeps when the battery dies. You can take the battery to a hardware store and buy a replacement for a couple of dollars, or call FiOS and they will send you a battery.

Those other deices you listed usually don't beep, except for the sump pump if it's got a water level alarm or a battery backup, but usually the water level alarm is constant. It may have indicator lights to tell you what's wrong.

Comment: Now that you mention it, the alarm beeps every 1 minute according to the manual.
https://www.verizon.com/support/residential/battery-backup/backup-unit

This beep is more like once in 2 hours.

Comment: I seem to recall the ONT manual was not accurate. I would unplug the battery and see if the resulting beep is the same tone.

Comment: If I unplug the battery, will I still have the internet connectivity in the house?

Comment: The unit I had worked as long as it still had AC power.

Comment: The ONT power supply has indicator lights to tell you the health of the battery.

Comment: My ONT has a 12V 7AH battery backup that costs a bit more than a couple dollars to replace. More like 20 to 40 dollars depending on what you choose to buy. For example https://www.amazon.com/Yuasa-NP7-12-Sealed-Battery-Terminal/dp/B00FA61Q1G/ref=sr_1_14?keywords=12V+7AH+battery&qid=1583989889&sr=8-14

Comment: I took out the battery from the ONT power supply. So far I haven't heard any beeps. It is Day 3 today.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you've been pranked?

A beep every two hours doesn't sound like something that would be designed into a product to make you aware of an issue

Consider a prank noise maker such as [Electronic Cricket](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0057M1384).

Comment: Are you kidding me? I've been chasing a beep for 5  years.  I think it's a smoke detector that was mounted in the rafters after a foam insulation ceiling went up.

Comment: to make matters worse, many of them have some randomization to the timing to further make it both hard to find and increase the level of frustration :\

Comment: To make matters more worse, some have a proximity sensor - besides randomization -  that will mute them if a person is in the same room or nearby.

Comment: while we are brainstorming off-beat ideas, I personally went looking for a smoke detector with a dying battery in my home for about a week, to the point of taking one down at a time and placing on my desk to see if it was the one chirping. Turned out that the person who composed the music in a video game used the chirp during a flame-themed battle.